# Delay carousel slide change after button click (Bootstrap)

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

How can i put a delay of 2 seconds for the Bootstrap carousel slides to change?

i'm using via data attributes. this is my carousel div:

```
<div id="carousel-content" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
```

Thanks.

Comment: which version of Bootstrap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**

After you commented with a link to your code, i saw that you are using carousel via data attributes.

add  `data-interval="2000"` to your carousel div

result:

```
<div id="carousel-content" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="2000">
```

---

Check out [Bootstrap's official documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel)

```
$('.carousel').carousel({
  interval: 2000
})
```

Comment: i thought its just when it slides automatically. i tried it and no change... i put the website here http://romullus.bl.ee please check it just in mobile version so browser width small, otherwise the mobile menu button doesnt appear.

Comment: i was adding it and now it changes the slides automatically:) not just when i click on a button...

Comment: i appreciate it very much:) the thing is i want that it doesnt change the slides automatically but just when i click on a menu item (and only after the menu closes) ...